# Elasticsearch: Aggregate known object keys (not values)

Tags: search, elasticsearch, aggregate

My Elasticsearch has an index with documents like this:

```
[{
  "_index": "products",
  "_type": "product",
  "_id": "100",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": "100",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "catalogue": {
      "categories": {
        "cat1": ['h1', 'spin2'],
        "cat5": ['h2', 'spin2']
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "_index": "products",
  "_type": "product",
  "_id": "100",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": "100",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "catalogue": {
      "categories": {
        "cat2": ['d1', 'spin2'],
        "cat5": ['h2', 'spin2']
      }
    }
  }
}]
```

I need to aggregate `known categories`. The expected result for the above is:

```
"aggregations": {
  "categories": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
        "key": "cat1",
        "doc_count": 1
      },
      {
        "key": "cat2",
        "doc_count": 1
      },
      {
        "key": "cat5",
        "doc_count": 2
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

How should I define my search call?

```
GET _search
{
  "aggregations": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        ???
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I should probably use the `script` key like below. This will probably have a performance impact, right?

```
GET _search
{
  "aggregations": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "script" : "????"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete mapping of `catalogue`?

Comment: @AndreiStefan That's all I have for now. In the future I'll add other keys thus I must not change the structure. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you down vote for this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
GET /products/product/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "cats": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "categories=_source.catalogue.categories;terms=[];for(categ in categories.keySet())terms+=categ;return terms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but, yes, it will have a performance impact. You need to test this and see how it behaves. Make sure you run the same query multiple times, as the first time might take longer to return, which is normal.